# Trying to figure out what resistor I need

Tags: resistors

My power source is 4 AAA batteries. The LED I'd like to use is a 2.65v ran at 1000mA. Does this mean a 3.3 ohm is sufficient?
Or a 3.2v ran at 700mA getting me a 4 ohm resistor?

Comment: All 4 in series? Off the top of my head I can't remember if AAA batteries can supply 1Amp and have a decent lifetime. Show us your calculations :)

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/140960/how-much-current-can-you-pull-safely-off-a-standard-aaa-battery

Comment: Your math is correct.  But as Wesley hinted, you will get a very short operating life from AAA's.  (Unless your only expecting brief flashes.)

Comment: Not to mentions the 3.3W you will be cooking out through that resistor

Comment: 6v-3.2v=2.8v/.7=4.

Comment: I'm trying to build a saber for my son with interchangeable LEDs and I'm trying to wrap my head around Ohm's law

Comment: 2W from a single LED is a lot of light for that application. Did you test it? Maybe your power requirements can be much lower keeping a similar perceived brightness. As an alternative, you can wire 12V LED strips directly to a 9V battery.

Answer (score 3):

You are far better off choosing a battery with more capacity and closer to load voltage.

e.g 3.6V LiPo with an active current limiter determined by Vbe =0.7V and I=Vbe/Re

The LED heat sink must be >1sq.in./W